# Git: Pushing to a remote repo from a remote repo?

Tags: git

I have a destination repo that is remote and I have a source repo
that is also remote. I would like my local machine to act as a proxy
to allow me to push to the destination from the source without ever
download the repo to my machine. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you say why do you want to do this? Perhaps we could find a workaround to achieve the same result...

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch the push command on the source remote.
You can make that through:

- a direct ssh session
- or a script called through an authorization layer like [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) through ssh.
  See [ADC (Admin Defined Commands)](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/ADCs.html)

> The admin-defined commands (ADCs) feature allows controlled access to specific, "safe", programs or scripts, without giving users full shell access.

Comment: That was my thought as well, but a "proxy" implies the two remotes don't have direct access to each other.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt then you need to somehow download the repo to your machine, which isn't what you want. The other option is to use a bundle (ie one file representing the repo), send it to an email address as an attached document. Or to a external space (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632723/git-with-dropbox/3633346#3633346: dropbox), in order for the other destination to download the bundle, and then pull from the bundle.

Comment: I suspect what I want to do just isn't possible as I do not have SSH access on either remote machine.

Comment: @bcardarella what I proposed in my previous comment doesn't involve SSH access: it is strictly between the two remote machines, not your intermediate local one.